# Amcharts serial chart data on specific date

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have problem using the Amcharts.

[image: Amchart]

I want to show zero on Jul 22 without amchart connect property.

Thanks

Comment: Insert a point with value of 0 on this day...

Comment: The question is not clear. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review the amcharts api:
https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#connect

> **connect** ... Specifies whether to connect data points if data is missing. The default value is true. This feature does not work with XY chart.

So, if you have a graph and you set the `connect` to `false`, and you have your "zero" value set to `null`, then the chart will not try to connect between points.

```
    "graphs": [{
    "connect": false,
    "id": "g1",
     ...
```

sample of part of the data provider with null value:

```
}, {
    "date": "2013-01-25",
    "value": 80
}, {
    "date": "2013-01-26",
    "value": null
}, {
    "date": "2013-01-27",
    "value": 84
}, {
    "date": "2013-01-28",
    "value": 83
}, {
```

example in jsfiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/6xv3ajgh/3/

[image]

Now, as to showing "zero", if you literally wanted to show a zero value even though the data in the provider has null, that is a bit of a different. Is that what you are asking?

Additionally, the more I think about it, you might end up seriously confusing the viewers of your chart if you do not show the zero value as connected to the rest of the points. **Zero** is **different** than **missing data**. If you have missing data for a day, then yes, you should not connect the points. But if you literally have a zero value, than I think you might be better off keeping the points connected.

Another related topic on the amCharts site you may be interested in viewing is how you can have different colors for a line (including "transparent" as a line color).

- https://www.amcharts.com/demos/line-with-changing-color/

Comment: Thanks your explanation. Connect property is good option missing data. If i can add on server side, will it be good practise?

Comment: Quite confusing that this question is getting accepted, as the question says: "I want to show zero on Jul 22 **without amchart connect property.**" Anyway... If you use the connect property you don't have to set the values you don't want to see to `null`. You can just leave them out completly.